# Library permission page does not show user

Tags: document-library

Site collection--> A Document library-> Library tools -> Library -> Library permission

It does not show specific users, it only shows Member, Visitor and Owner.

How can I see permissions for specific users?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you grant permissions to a user explicitly it will show up there.

Here if you click grant permissions and give permissions to user it will show up.

Comment: please mark this as answer if it solves your problem.